# Latitude and Longitude Issue with out of the boundary values

Tags: php, solr

I have a strange issue. I'm parsing the feed into the SOLR index and one of the fields is the latlon (location) field type. Everything works fine, but I've stumbled upon a strange latitude and the longitude data within the feed, so my import into SOLR failed with error:

```
Bad X value -245.0791883469 is not in boundary Rect(minX=-180.0,maxX=180.0,minY=-90.0,maxY=90.0)
```

The input was (lat,lon) : -8.1832432059,-245.0791883469

I know that the latitude must be within -180 and 180, and I've made a latitude & longitude validation for those fields which I've skipped. BUT, when I used this service http://www.latlong.net/Show-Latitude-Longitude.html
to check this weird latitude and longitude data, I was surprised that they actually converts the wrong latitude input to the correct one (which basically **matches the location in my feed**, except that I have the wrong longitude). Or I really miss something out... Screenshot:

[image]

So I'm wondering if there is some kind of formula to do that? To convert latitude/longitude values out of regular boundaries?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Solved. If any of you stumble across this problem, the really simple solution is to add/subtract the 360 from a longitude. Some feeds have a full 360 degrees longitude radius, and to convert those to 2D points - longitude value less than -180 will have 360 added to it, and a longitude value greater than 180 will have 360 subtracted from it. This works of course if the longitude and latitude as a pair is not obsolete.

Comment: Are you sure it converts it to the correct value?  At the bottom it does say "Invalid Input Value".

Comment: Yes it says. But look at the yellow marked longitude at the bottom. This is basically the corrected value. and the strange thing is that this value exactly points to the item in my feed. I've tried to change the longitude point at the top and it always corrects the wrong input to it's correct value (always different of course)... Dunno.. Totally confused